# Gnuplot plot data from different files

Tags: csv, graph, gnuplot

I'm looking for a way to plot data from different files into one graph.

I'm testing different approaches to a problem. I have some parameters and I'm trying to conclude how the results are related to these parameters. I run some tests on the different solutions I'm comparing, and I redo this several times with different parameters.

So I have several .csv files looking like this.

```
       test1    test2    test3    test4   ...
sol1     1        1        1        1 
sol2     1        1        1        1 
sol3     1        1        1        1 
sol4     1        1        1        1 
...
```

(These are of course filled with real data and not just 1's)

I want to plot a graph where the Y axis is the result of (for example) test1/sol1 and the x axis plots the different parameter values (the different .csv files).

I hope I have made clear what i'm trying to create.

I am hoping there is a way of doing this directly in gnuplot. The file structure is this way in order to create some other graphs, so I don't really want to change it.

I read about the possibility of concatenating two files, but i don't really see that of being much use here.

EDIT: (thanks to Christoph) I want to plot the value in the cell test1/sol1 vs my parameter. The parameter is changing per file. So I need to read 1 datapoint per file.

In the end I would like to plot this information for different solutions in one graph. So for the cells test1/sol1, test1/sol2, test1/sol3,...

In the example below, the x axis would be the changing parameter, the Y axis would be the value in the corresponding cell from column 'test1' and the different lines correspond to the different solutions.

[image: graph example]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://wiki.visvis.googlecode.com/hg/images/examples/example_plotting.png))</sub>

(random image from google)

I hope it's clearer now what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to plot: What is `test1/sol1` supposed to be on the y-axis? Do you want to plot the value in the cell `test1/sol1` vs. the respective parameter (contained in the filename?)? You could do that with iterations like `plot for [file in filelist]`, but that won't work with lines, only with boxes, or points etc. Also, possible solutions depend on other values, which you want to include in the plot: should `sol1` appear somewhere or `test1`? What about the parameter value etc.

Comment: Hi Christoph. Thanks for your reply. I indeed want to plot the value in the cell test1/sol1 vs the parameter. The parameter is simply 1,2,3,4... (and is contained in the filename). The values in the cells are percentages, but that shouldn't really matter. I want to use lines because I want to put multiple plots (test1/sol2, test1/sol3,...) on the same graph to compare them.

Comment: Ok, because you cannot connect points stemming from different files with lines. That one of the main points why one needs to concatenate several files. Or you plot inside `set table` and then replot it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, as I'm not yet very experienced with Gnuplot, but I managed to do it like this:

```
sol1 = "< (cat param0.csv param1.csv param2.csv | grep sol1)"
plot sol1 using 2 with lines title "sol1"
```

So `cat` this will put the files with different parameter after each other, and then I only keep the lines with `sol1` in them. Then I just plot the first column (values for test1)

I just repeat this for the different solutions, with copy paste (since the number of solutions is fixed, this appeared to be the easiest way).

Comment: You could use gnuplot iterations to ease this, something like `sol(x) = sprintf('< (cat param0.csv param1.csv param2.csv) | grep sol%d', x); plot for [i=1:5] sol(i) using 2 with lines title sprintf('sol%d', i)`

Comment: cool! I wasn't aware that you could use gnuplot variables inside the commands. Thanks!